# regexp pattern across multiple lines

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a long regexp pattern that needs to be matched in TCL

```
regexp {.*%MKA-5-SESSION_START: +\((.*) +:.*\) +MKA Session started for.*([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}).*AuditSessionID +(.*), +AuthMgr-Handle +(.*)} $op - intf mac auditsessid authmgrhdl
```

How can i split this to multiple lines , splitting using \ is not working as regexp fails.

Thanks,
Agnel.

Answer (score 3):

That is a monster RE. The easiest way to split it up would be to use an extended mode RE by putting `(?x)` at the start of it, which makes whitespace meaningless in the RE (you then also have to use `\s` to match real whitespace)

It's also useful in this situation to put the RE in its own variable. It's just clearer.

```
set RE {(?x)
    # We can use comments in extended mode too! This is useful for sanity's sake…
    .*
    # Detect and match for 'intf'
    %MKA-5-SESSION_START:\s+\((.*)\s+:.*\)\s+
    # Detect and match for 'mac'
    MKA\sSession\sstarted\sfor.*([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}.[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}).*
    # Detect and match for 'auditsessid'
    AuditSessionID\s+(.*),\s+
    # Detect and match for 'authmgrhdl'
    AuthMgr-Handle\s+(.*)
}
```

Then you just match it as normal, with `regexp`, which is clearer now that we've separated the RE itself out:

```
regexp $RE $op -> intf mac auditsessid authmgrhdl
```

It's usually a good idea to check the result of `regexp` to see if things matched.

Comment: If you want a matchable newline in a pattern, use `\n`…

Comment: @agnel, you'll want to read the Tcl [re_syntax man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), particularly the section about ["metasyntax"](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M82)