# Tcl split regex over multiple lines

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a long RE to match dates in multiple files and I would like to split it out over multiple lines so it is easier to read and update. I am setting it as a variable and then calling that variable in the regex statement.

```
set ::eval::regexdate { \d[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|\d{4}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}|(([12]\d|3[01])|([12]\d|3[01])(th|nd|rd|st))\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d{4}|(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4} }
```

I am then calling it with the following regexp line...

```
if {[regexp "($::eval::regexdate)" $linefromfile all date]} {
    Do something...
 }
```

This all works fine if the RE is set as one long string, but if I try to break it out over multiple lines using (?x) as outlined in this post.

[regexp pattern across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791814/regexp-pattern-across-multiple-lines)

```
set ::eval::regexdate {(?x)
    \d[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|
    \d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|
    \d{4}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}|
    (([12]\d|3[01])|([12]\d|3[01])(th|nd|rd|st))\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d{4}|
    (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}
}
```

I get the following error...

```
 `couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid.`
```

I am not sure why this is happening, my understanding is that using (?x) ignores all white space and comments so it should just stitch the lines back together to create the one long RE, no? Are the "|" operands causing an issue in the way that I have split the RE up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated in figuring out why it won't work when using (?x).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you use the regexdate variable in your regxep command. As the post you reference indicates, `(?x)` should be at the start of the regular expression. However, by using `"($::eval::regexdate)"` you put parentheses around it, effectively making the expression `((?x)…)`. Putting parentheses around the complete regular expression is not very useful, as the regexp command will already put the full match in the first variable handed to it.

So, either omit the parentheses and use the complete match as the date:

```
regexp $::eval::regexdate $linefromfile date
```

Or move the `(?x)` to the call:

```
set ::eval::regexdate {
    \d[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|
    \d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}|
    \d{4}[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{2}|
    (([12]\d|3[01])|([12]\d|3[01])(th|nd|rd|st))\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d{4}|
    (JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[\/\.-]\d{2}[\/\.-]\d{4}
}

if {[regexp "(?x)($::eval::regexdate)" $linefromfile all date]} {
    Do something...
}
```

Comment: Also note that the two regular expressions are not exactly equivalent. Your one-liner has a space at both ends. This is not the case with the multi-line version. Based on the provided information, it is not possible to tell whether the spaces were intentional.

Comment: Thanks Schelte, moving the (?x) to the call made the difference. I guess I was confused over where it should have been placed. Not in the variable but in the regexp line itself. Simple fixes, eh? ! :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's fine to put the (?x) in the variable, as long as it stays at the start of the regular expression if you combine the variable with other stuff.